# Executable jar with scala and maven

Tags: scala, maven, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to create executable jar with scala and maven. I am using maven-scala-plugin and maven-assembly-plugin, but it seems to me that assembly plugin is ignored. I am getting jar without dependencies and containing manifest without main-class row.

```
   <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.example.MainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: What command are you using to build? You may want to check the lower part of the accepted answer to [this very popular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) and perhaps add an `executions` section. Notice also the comments, which suggest other helpful questions.

Comment: maven-scala-plugin is deprecated, replaced by scala-maven-plugin since 2+ years. the scala-plugin doesn't modify dependencies, etc. I thinks your issue come from maven-assembly-plugin usage.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution ,wish it is helpful for you .
Add the following to you pom.xml

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.scala</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>xxx.xxx.xxx.Main</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>reference.conf</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: I was struggling since yesterday and finally found this. Thanks a lot for your solution!!

Answer (score 0):

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.example.MyClass</mainClass>
                        <classpathLayoutType>custom</classpathLayoutType>
                        <customClasspathLayout>lib/$${artifact.artifactId}-$${artifact.version}$${dashClassifier?}.$${artifact.extension}</customClasspathLayout>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Be sure that directory target/lib exist.